# Python re.search - searching from left to right

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I've got a small problem. I've written a module to parse a configuration file (wvdial's wvdial.conf) using regex. File contains strings like `"Init1 = AT"` and I've used a following regex:

```
match = re.match(r'(.*)=(.*)', line)
```

Everything worked until following line:

```
#Init3 = AT+CPIN="0000"
```

Which got parsed like:

```
'#Init3 = AT+CPIN':'0000'
```

It seems like the regex engine goes from right to left parsing the string. Is there any way to reverse the re.search direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark your first `*` quantifier as non-greedy by appending `?`:

```
match = re.match(r'(.*?)=(.*)', line)
```

Demo:

```
>>> line = '#Init3 = AT+CPIN="0000"'
>>> re.match(r'(.*?)=(.*)', line).group()
'#Init3 = AT+CPIN="0000"'
```

By making the quantifier non-greedy, the regular expression engine will match the *minimum* to satisfy the pattern, rather than the maximum.

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly the option I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

No python re doesn't parse from right to left **but** .* is by default *greedy* it will look for the longest match it can get, you can get your regex to work in a couple of ways easiest is:

```
re.match(r'([^=]+)=(.*)', line)
```

This will match anything but = as the first part of the match then = then anything after the first =

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> line = '#Init3 = AT+CPIN="0000"'
>>> re.match(r'([^=]+)=(.*)', line).groups()
('#Init3 ', ' AT+CPIN="0000"')
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the wrong tool. It seems wvdial.conf is really an *.ini* file format. Python comes with the `ConfigParser` module, which can easily handle it:

```
import ConfigParser

# Sample wvdial.conf
'''
[Dialer Defaults] 
Modem = /dev/ttyS2 
Baud = 57600 

[Dialer shh] 
Init3 = ATM0

[Dialer pulse] 
Dial Command = ATDP
'''

configuration = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
configuration.read('wvdial.conf')
init3 = configuration.get('Dialer shh', 'Init3') # ATM0
print init3
```